# How to avoid MacPorts conflict with /usr/local

Tags: macports

Since MacPorts is not compatible with /usr/local *, whenever I install/update ports with MacPorts I would

```
sudo mv /usr/local /usr/local.bak
```

and after I am done building MacPorts stuff

```
sudo mv /usr/local.bak /usr/local
```

This works and solves a lot of the previous mysterious build errors. However it is very cumbersome and sometimes I don't remember to do this, either the "before" step or the "after" step, and have to fix it afterward.

Is there a better way to avoid this conflict?

EDIT
* see these links for examples/suggestions of temporarily moving `/usr/local` as a solution to MacPort build problems.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827377/install-git-core-svn-fails-with-macport

https://trac.macports.org/ticket/21649

https://trac.macports.org/ticket/29998

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand what `/usr/local` conflicts you're talking about. MacPorts intentionally uses its own `/opt` hierarchy in order to avoid conflicting with anything you already had in `/usr/local`. It shouldn't be putting anything in `/usr/local` unless perhaps you changed its configuration.

Were you thinking of Homebrew? I believe Homebrew still puts things in `/usr/local` by default, whereas MacPorts uses `/opt` and Fink uses `/sw`.

So I guess my "better way to avoid this conflict" is to use MacPorts instead of Homebrew, and leave MacPorts set to its default prefix of `/opt`.

Comment: I am using MacPorts; and I don't have Homebrew. Please see the edit for why I am doing this.

I am curious why you don't have this issue though. I have checked my path and it points to `/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/subversion/bin:` before anything from `/usr/local`. But this is still an issue.

Comment: MacPorts cannot isolate itself away from `/usr/local`, as this path is in the default search path of the compiler and cannot be removed.